# how to post using auth for api in python

Tags: python, json, api, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-405

I was trying to see if the URL not found do post request for it but I'mm facing 405 error:

```py
response=request.head(f'https://cdvra82a44.welldone.com:8454/api/v/account/{cm_nm}/user,',
auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin','admin'))
url=f'https://cdvra82a44.welldone.com:8454/api/v/account/{cm_nm}'

print(response)

if response.status==404:
    print(response.statuse_code)
    headars={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    username='user'
    password='pass'
    responses=requests.post(url,json=JsonString,auth=.(username,password),headars=headars)
    print(responses.status_code)
else:
    print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: `headars` should be `headers`, it might have an impact on your logic

Comment: I have change it but still same error

Comment: 405 is method not allowed - in the 405 message, the server should have an "allow" header field, that should tell you what methods the server is expecting.

Comment: so what should i do i just need the post method to work